# magento2 cron schedule not running, cannot understand why

Tags: magento2, cron

Crontab

```
* * * * * php -c /opt/alt/php56/etc <magento2_path>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento2_path>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * php -c /opt/alt/php56/etc <magento2_path>/update/cron.php >> <magento2_path>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * php -c /opt/alt/php56/etc <magento2_path>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento2_path>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Backend configuration:
Group index:

```
Generate Schedules Every    1   
Schedule Ahead for          4
Missed if Not Run Within    10
History Cleanup Every       10
Success History Lifetime    60
Failure History Lifetime    600
Use Separate Process        Yes
```

Group default:

```
Generate Schedules Every    15  
Schedule Ahead for          20
Missed if Not Run Within    15
History Cleanup Every       10
Success History Lifetime    60
Failure History Lifetime    600
Use Separate Process        No
```

magento.cron.log and update.cron.log show this:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.19
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

bin/magento must be run as a CLI application
```

When I add new products in the catalog the reindex does not happen and the products do not show on the frontend. On the other hand, when I place orders the buyer get the transaction mail.
A manual run of `cron:run` or `indexer:reindex` works properly from SSH and the indexes get reindexed.
What am I missing? It's been days and I can't get through it.

UPDATE: changing the crontab rows from `php` to `php-cli`results in clear logs, but still the indexing has to be done manually. The scheduling and execution of cron jobs runs smoothly, according to the table `cron_schedule` in the database.

Comment: so 'X-Powered-By' indicate it was apache's php, you figured it out, nice. what about the indexing, did you solve that one ?